# unable to uninstall angular 1.7.4 from windows

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, angular5

I am trying to change the angular version from 1.7.4 to 1.6.8 but even after running uninstall i m still getting older angular version.I have tried uninstalling nodejs as well. I have tried the following command to remove existing angular version

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@1.7.4`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm cache verify --force`

current node version is 8.12.0 and angular 1.7.4

Comment: Do you see any errors? Also, you are trying to downgrade the angular CLI (and not angular) right? If so, what angular CLI version do you see when running the comment `ng --version`?

Comment: no error, on ng -v i get v1.7.4 i.e even after uninstalling its showing me version

Comment: Didn't you have @angular/cli installed locally? Check your package.json.

Comment: @magos i want to change my global installation

Comment: I see, but if you have local installation `ng -v` command returns local version. You could mistakenly assume the global one still exists. The next thing I can think about is - do you use NVM?

Comment: i checked i m out of project directory. I am using npm